# Combine Material-UI with other frameworks like Foundation

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, zurb-foundation, material-ui

I have something on my mind for quite a while but couldn't find an answer to it. Consider the following:

You like to build a fancy website with React and have to decide which front-end framework you should use. In my example I have chosen Material-UI.
Now you came to a point where you need more features like a responsive grid system, show/hide styles etc. Instead of implementing them on your own (or copying it from bootstrap/foundation, for example) you think: 'Hey, why wouldn't I include another framework beside Material-UI'.

Now comes the question. I know that most of the css frameworks available have their own normalisation css and basic styles for typography and other elements.
**Can I safely include another (more featured) css framework beside Material-UI without breaking fundamental things or should I avoid that?**

Furthermore, what is a good practice approach to extend the css features without copying parts from other frameworks and without reinventing the wheel all the time. Did you ever had a case or project where you had to combine multiple front-end frameworks and how did you solve this problem?

Thanks for your feedback.

Cheers
Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, there's a *Material Design* version of Foundation, you can check it out at http://eucalyptuss.github.io/material-foundation/

Now, talking about your doubts... one should be very careful when mixing and/or using more than one framework at the same time... one issue can be conflict, other can be unnecessary bloating which could make load time heavier.

However, if you are aware of that, most of modern frameworks (as Foundation) can be compiled partially, so you will be loading only the stuff you'll use, minimizing all possible issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have been thinking this exactly thing lately.. I would choose one that has most of the features i need in my project. I usually go just with Bootstrap (sass version) and use only the styling part of that (css grids mostly).

Mixing frameworks will eventually be hard to maintain and you have to include lot of extra (unused) features into your application. When using some "cool", full featured components like Material-UI has, there will still be times when some component doesn't have just the property you would need.

So my opinion is:

- Use some framework for styling only. This way you have uniform look in your site. Or even just some responsive grid library could be enough.
- Usually basic html components are enough to fill basic needs, you can just build your own custom components for special needs (or use some from npm library). This way you have just the features you need.
- This way my site is not depending just some single framework. I can change the styling part anytime, i can change one component to another etc. without having to re-write my whole application just because it's been developed entirely with some "full featured" framework.